# Changing the Root View Controller in App Delegate

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I need to take care of two things

1)If user not logged in my app, i need to show the LoginVC ,and then passwordVC and VC3 ..

2)if user already logged in i need to show the passwordVC and then VC3

For scenarios **2**  i have created one more navigation controller with VC3 , i gave identifier for the newly created navigation controller .And now i have created one more **passwordVC** to be present that on second scenarios. Present Newly created password screen on VC3.So after entering the correct password ,i need to dismiss the newly created **PasswordVC** and should show VC3.

I have done the 1 St scenarios. i just check the keychain and i left because i am having the LoginVC with navigation controller as initial view controller.here is my code for 1 scenario

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
KeychainItemWrapper *keyChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"Login" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *str = [keyChain objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
if (str.length == 0) {  
   //here i have commented those lines becausee i having initial view controller as navigation controller in my storyboard.
       //            self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
       //            CognitoHomeViewController *Login = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginVC"];
        //[self.window setRootViewController:Login];
     }
    else{

       PasscodePinViewController *PasscodePinViewController=[[PasscodePinViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PasscodePinViewController" bundle:nil];            
        [self presentviewcontroller:PasscodePinViewController];}
```

i else part i need to change....
for 2nd scenarios i have created the navigation controller and new PasswordVC. i am managing the 2 scenarios in my app delegate using keychain .if user name exist on keychain i need to do 2nd scenario if not 1 st scenarios .

The thing is i don't to how to perform the 2nd scenarios in app delegateclass.Please help me to do this ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this in AppDelegate at all. Create a WelcomeVC and make it root controller and check if user is logged in or not in the welcome VC, and you can segue to loginVC or to passwordVC based on condition.

Comment: @ Teja Nandamuri I am not using segue all moving from one view controller to another through coding only. And then why should I want to create a vc again

Comment: I want to do it my app delegate only ...please suggest some examples and help me to do this

Comment: Segue is a way to do, you dont have to use segues, you can do all the coding in welcomeVC. App Delegate is not a place to do all these things. Down the road your app delegate will look nasty if you keep doing these things. It makes a lot of difference if you use welcomeVC as root controller.

Comment: I am doing with segue only .we can go to next view controller using view controllers object .so like that only .Please help me .

Comment: Please anyone help me to do this .